# "includes" Javascript Function Not Working in WSO2 ESB script mediator

Tags: javascript, function, wso2, mediator, wso2-esb

"includes" Javascript Function Not Working in WSO2 ESB script mediator. I have tried this using WSO2ESB.

```
<script language="js"><![CDATA[        
                var dateFromPayload = mc.getProperty("dateFrom");
                var dateToPayload = mc.getProperty("dateTo")                

                function compareDates() {
                    var result = false;
                    print("hiiiii");
                    print(dateFromPayload.toString());
                    print(dateToPayload.toString());
                    var test= "dddd";
                    if (dateFromPayload.toString().includes("/") || dateToPayload.toString().includes("/")) {
                        result = false;
                    } else {

                        var dateFrom = new Date(dateFromPayload);
                        var dateTo = new Date(dateToPayload);
                        result = dateFrom.getTime() <= dateTo.getTime();
                         if (!result) {
                            result = false;
                    }
                }
                mc.setProperty("fromToDateValidated", result);
                }; compareDates()]]></script>
```

Comment: if (dateFromPayload.toString().includes("/") || dateToPayload.toString().includes("/")) { line includes function gives an error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This could be due to underlying javascript engine used in the ESB does not support the `includes()` function yet. The underlying javascript engine is mozilla rhino and the version is 1.7R4. It could be that this version does not support the above function `includes()` as it is included from ECMAScript 6.

As an alternative approach, you could use `indexOf()` function as below.

```
if (dateFromPayload.toString().indexOf("/") != -1) {
    result = false;
}
```